# Remove a object from array using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to remove a product from the user's cart when I delete it from the web, but I don't know how to do it.

The moongoose schema of User is the following:

```js
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
      email: { type: String, required: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true },
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      surname: { type: String, required: true },
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      birth: { type: Date, required: true },
      cartItems: {
          type: [{
              qty: { type: Number, required: true },
              product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }
          }]
      }
});
```

I want to remove an item from cartItems. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.update(
  { _id: id },
  { $pull: { 'cartItems.type': { product: '....' } } }
);
```

more about [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)